# Sql Joins on multiple table returning product of two columns

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am trying to generate a report on a sql server database in asp.net and I am getting the results of some columns as a product of two columns. Here is the code

```
   comm.CommandText = "SELECT Count(Courses.CourseID) AS CourseCount, Count(Students.StudentID) AS StudentCount, Schools.Name, Schools.StartDate, Schools.SchoolFees " +
                "FROM Schools" +
                "LEFT JOIN Courses ON (Schools.SchoolID = Courses.SchoolID)" +
                "LEFT JOIN Students ON (Schools.SchoolID = Students.SchoolID) " +
                "WHERE Schools.Active = 1 " +
                "GROUP BY Schools.Name, Schools.StartDate, Schools.SchoolFees";
```

When I run the code, the result displays, but the columns for "CourseCount" and "StudentCount" display a value that is a product of each individual column. "CourseCount" is normally 288 and "StudentCount" is 38 but when I run the code, both "CourseCount" and "StudentCount" display 10944 which is 38 x 288.

Anyway I can make them display the correct values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your code from using a count of all rows, to a count of distinct values only, should return the results you expect

```
comm.CommandText = "SELECT Count(DISTINCT Courses.CourseID) AS CourseCount, Count(DISTINCT Students.StudentID) AS StudentCount, Schools.Name, Schools.StartDate, Schools.SchoolFees " +
            "FROM Schools" +
            "LEFT JOIN Courses ON (Schools.SchoolID = Courses.SchoolID)" +
            "LEFT JOIN Students ON (Schools.SchoolID = Students.SchoolID) " +
            "WHERE Schools.Active = 1 " +
            "GROUP BY Schools.Name, Schools.StartDate, Schools.SchoolFees";
```

The results being returned are technically correct, if all schools have courses, and all courses have students

Comment: Worked well ! Thanks alot @rossquan.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, it is how you are using the COUNT (), You are asking it to count all, which is why it returns so many. Use count on just the two values you want counted.

Answer (score 0):

This might perform better than the DISTINCT Count method..

```
comm.CommandText = 
    "SELECT cc.CourseCount, sc.StudentCount, Schools.Name, Schools.StartDate, Schools.SchoolFees " +
    "FROM Schools" +
    "OUTER APPLY (SELECT Count(Students.StudentID) StudentCount FROM Students WHERE Students.SchoolID = Schools.SchoolID) sc " +
    "OUTER APPLY (SELECT Count(Courses.CourseID) CourseCount FROM Courses WHERE Courses.SchoolID = Schools.SchoolID) cc " +
    "WHERE Schools.Active = 1 ";
```